# Disable certain ListBox items

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

What is the best way to disable certain items of my ListBox..? I have the following code in XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="ScenarioList" Grid.Row="1" SelectionChanged="ScenarioControl_SelectionChanged"
             SelectionMode="Single" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ScenarioListBoxStyle}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}"
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ScenarioBinder}}" Style="{StaticResource ListItemTextStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I am binding data in the code behind and using the following IValueConverter to bind data to my TextBox

```
    public class ScenarioBindingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var keyValPair = value as KeyValuePair<Feature, bool>?;
        return !keyValPair.HasValue ? DependencyProperty.UnsetValue : keyValPair.Value.Key.DisplayName();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

the Feature object has a IsEnabled property which I would like to Bind directly to the ListBox items and if the item is disabled, the list box item needs to be grayed out.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

As per your code, if you're using `<StackPanel>` or `<TextBlock>` in your data template then you'll not get `IsEnabled` property of these two Elements to bind with. Instead you can use `IsHitTestVisible` property to enable or disable tapping event on those Elements.

But by setting `IsHitTestVisible` the element will not turn gray so, you'll have to bind the `Foreground` color by assigning `SolidColorBrush` value to textblock as well.

```
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel ... IsHitTestVisible="{Binding Converter={StaticResource HitTestVisibleConverter}">
                    <TextBlock ... />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

with that, use the converter to Bind the `IsEnabled` property value that you have, with `IsHitTestVisible` property.

hope that helps..!
Ask if further help requires..

Comment: Thanks for getting back and your solution makes perfect sense!! Also, is there there is a different (and simple approach) to list a set of items and selectively disable them using data bindings?